# Intellij IDEA: Java cannot find getRandomElement

Tags: java

I want to make a simple number guessing game, but I cannot print a random number, because java will not let me use getRandomElement.

Compiler error:

> ```
> The method getRandomElement() is undefined for the type Main
> ```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    // Drive Function 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create a list of Integer type 
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // add 5 element in ArrayList 
        list.add(10);
        list.add(20);
        list.add(30);
        list.add(40);
        list.add(50);

        Main obj = new Main();

        // take a random element from list and print them 
        System.out.println(obj.getRandomElement(list));
    }
}
```

Comment: "not let me use" is not a clear problem for those who view your question, please explain more about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `getRandomElement` method in your class, you forgot to create/copy as [method in example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomly-select-items-from-a-list-in-java/)

> ```
> public int getRandomElement(List<Integer> list) 
> { 
>     Random rand = new Random(); 
>     return list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size())); 
> }
> ```